# Como retornar o nome de um objeto existente em um JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho o arquivo JSON abaixo:

```
{
  "uid1":{
    "start_time":"20140815",
    "name":"name 1"
    },
  "uid2":{
    "start_time":"20141229",
    "name":"name 2"
    },
  "uid3":{
    "start_time":"20140809",
    "name":"name 3"
    },
  "uid4":{
    "start_time":"20140830",
    "name":"name 4"
    },
  "uid5":{
    "start_time":"20140920",
    "name":"name 5"
    }
}
```

Preciso não só retornar os valores dentro de cada "**uid**" mas também o próprio "**nome**" do "**uid**" onde o resultado seja algo assim:

```
uid1,20140815,name 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer algo assim:

```
var obj = {
    "uid1": {
        "start_time": "20140815",
            "name": "name 1"
    },
        "uid2": {
        "start_time": "20141229",
            "name": "name 2"
    },
        "uid3": {
        "start_time": "20140809",
            "name": "name 3"
    },
        "uid4": {
        "start_time": "20140830",
            "name": "name 4"
    },
        "uid5": {
        "start_time": "20140920",
            "name": "name 5"
    }
};

// Montagem dos resultados.

var resultado = [];

for (var prop in obj) {
    resultado.push(prop + ',' + obj[prop].start_time + ',' + obj[prop].name);
}

// Exibição dos resultados.

for (var i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++) {
    alert(resultado[i]);
}
```

Comment: perfeito bernardo,

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer desta forma

***JQuery***

```
var json = {
  "uid1":{
    "start_time":"20140815",
    "name":"name 1"
    },
  "uid2":{
    "start_time":"20141229",
    "name":"name 2"
    },
  "uid3":{
    "start_time":"20140809",
    "name":"name 3"
    },
  "uid4":{
    "start_time":"20140830",
    "name":"name 4"
    },
  "uid5":{
    "start_time":"20140920",
    "name":"name 5"
    }
};

$(function(){
    $.each(json, function(i, v){
       $('ul').append('<li>'+ i + ', ' + v.start_time + ', ' + v.name +'</li>'); 
    });
});
```

O exemplo acima popula um elemento `<ul>`, use para adaptar a sua aplicação.

Você também pode ver esta **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/hw4zb/)** com o exemplo funcionando